# How to NOT add Google account to Android phone while using Google Sign-In Button

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-account, google-identity

I'm [integrating Google-Sign button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) in my android app. However, whenever another user logs in with his credentials, the Google account is being added to Settings > Users & Accounts section on the phone. This should not happen.

For example, assume **aarav@gmail.com** is there under U & A section. Now, if **alex@gmail.com** is logging in the app on Aarav's phone, then Alex's Google account shouldn't be added to the phone.

Right now that is not the case. How can this be done?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that the Google Sign-in uses an already existing Google account. Like if you are logged into your account with your phone, google sign in uses that account to sign into the app. Am I right?

Comment: That’s right. However, it adds ALL the accounts, to the phone, which are used to login in the app. Looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: Android can handle more than a logged google account and I don't think it's possible to do something like remove an old account when logging with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another Google account for android. First of all, you have to log in with your previous Google account which was added in the android device and after that remove that account. After removing the previous account you can add a new Google Account.

Because of the Andriod sync process, it checks your newly added account with the previous account. If it doesn't match it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the account first, then after that you can delete it from settings.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to avoid adding the account in the U&A section in the first place. To delete an account, the app would require more permissions. Also, there is a risk of deleting the primary accounts of the user. If that happens, then all the user's data such as contacts, etc are gone from the phone. Want to avoid all of that.